# Concatenar helpers de laravel en javascript

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

como puedo concatenar este helper.

```
$('#foto4').append('<img src="{{ asset('+ subCate[i].imagen +') }}" alt="" class="slidIMG img-fluid" >');
```

No reconoce el contenido del helper, lo imprime tal cual, alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible pero no muy recomendado ya que laravel se ejecuta del lado del servidor, mientras que Jquery se ejecuta del lado del cliente o navegador

```
$('#foto4').append('<img src="{{ asset("images") }}'+ subCate[i].imagen +'" alt="" class="slidIMG img-fluid" >');
```

De esta forma mediante laravel generas la parte de la ruta hasta la carpeta public/images, y con js completas hasta la imagen.

P.D. debes agregar al menos una carpeta en el helper de asset si no te arrojara un error.

Yo te recomiendo que realices una petición por Ajax para solicitar los datos que necesitas.

JavaScript

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('get.asset') }}",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        asset:subCate[i].imagen
    },
}).done(function(data){
   $('#foto4').append('<img src="'data'" alt="" class="slidIMG img-fluid" >');
});
```

Ruta

```
Route::post('/get-asset', 'AssetController@getAsset')->name('get.asset');
```

Controlador

```
public function getAsset(Request $request){
   
   $asset = public_path('images/'.$request->asset);      
   return response()->json($asset);

}
```

Esta serian una de tantas formas posibles.